# Average of certain hours

Tags: python, pandas, average

Basically, what I need is an hourly average of an existing table (see below).

The input file initially is in 15 minute granularity. The Output should show an average of each day and an average of the hours 8am -8pm of each day in a separate column.

```
DateTime            Value               Date Output Average (entire day)    Average (8am - 8pm)
09/01/2017 00:00    5055.414058 ->  09/01/2017      
09/01/2017 00:15    5055.414058     10/01/2017      
09/01/2017 00:30    5055.414058     11/01/2017      
09/01/2017 00:45    5055.414058     12/01/2017      
09/01/2017 01:00    5986.204028     13/01/2017      
09/01/2017 01:15    5986.204028     14/01/2017      
09/01/2017 01:30    5986.204028     15/01/2017      
09/01/2017 01:45    5986.204028     16/01/2017      
09/01/2017 02:00    7199.824865     17/01/2017      
09/01/2017 02:15    7199.824865     18/01/2017      
09/01/2017 02:30    7199.824865     19/01/2017      
09/01/2017 02:45    7199.824865     20/01/2017      
09/01/2017 03:00    9185.008333     21/01/2017      
09/01/2017 03:15    9185.008333     22/01/2017      
09/01/2017 03:30    9185.008333     23/01/2017      
…                   
13/01/2017 22:00    94080.58174             
13/01/2017 22:15    94080.58174             
13/01/2017 22:30    94080.58174             
13/01/2017 22:45    94080.58174             
13/01/2017 23:00    93231.23486             
13/01/2017 23:15    93231.23486             
13/01/2017 23:30    93231.23486             
13/01/2017 23:45    93231.23486             
14/01/2017 00:00    91619.33743             
14/01/2017 00:15    91619.33743             
14/01/2017 00:30    91619.33743             
14/01/2017 00:45    91619.33743             
14/01/2017 01:00    89894.48751             
14/01/2017 01:15    89894.48751             
14/01/2017 01:30    89894.48751             
…
```

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
import glob
import csv

# Local path and name of the excel file.
path = 'W:/myfolder/'
sheetname = "Forecast_" + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d.%m.%Y-%H')
filename = path + sheetname + ".csv"

#Create data frame of data
df = pd.read_csv(filename ,delimiter=',',engine = 'python', encoding='latin-1', index_col = False)
print(df)

table = df.groupby([df["DateTime"].dt.day, df["DateTime"].dt.hour]).mean()

print(table)
```

Comment: what about `df.mean()` ? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Is your code not working?

Answer (score 1):

Simply you just need to create a first column containing the date (expressed as the day) and do a groupby + aggregate.

I'll post code asap :)

EDIT: as promised the code,

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import os

folderPath = "data/"

#Put all dataframes together
def folderIterator(folderPath):
    for item in os.listdir(folderPath):
        yield pd.read_csv("{:s}{:s}".format(folderPath, item))

dfIterator =  folderIterator(folderPath)
fullDataFrame = dfIterator.next()
for df in dfIterator:
    fullDataFrame = fullDataFrame.append(df)

#Create date column
fullDataFrame["DayCol"] = fullDataFrame["DateTime"].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')).map(lambda x: x.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
finalDF = fullDataFrame.groupby("DayCol").mean()

print finalDF
```

Ask any question about the code :)

Answer (score 0):

use `pd.TimeGrouper`, `query`, and `pd.concat`

```
tidx = pd.date_range('2016-03-30', '2016-04-01', freq='2H')

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(value=np.random.rand(len(tidx))), tidx)

from8to8 = df.assign(hour=df.index.hour).query('8 >= hour < 9') \
    .groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).value.mean().rename('8to8')
daily = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).value.mean().rename('day')
pd.concat([df.value, daily, from8to8], axis=1).ffill()



                        value       day      8to8
2016-03-30 00:00:00  0.671287  0.565916  0.704173
2016-03-30 02:00:00  0.997307  0.565916  0.704173
2016-03-30 04:00:00  0.335283  0.565916  0.704173
2016-03-30 06:00:00  0.722650  0.565916  0.704173
2016-03-30 08:00:00  0.794335  0.565916  0.704173
2016-03-30 10:00:00  0.992366  0.565916  0.704173
2016-03-30 12:00:00  0.206157  0.565916  0.704173
2016-03-30 14:00:00  0.480467  0.565916  0.704173
2016-03-30 16:00:00  0.389169  0.565916  0.704173
2016-03-30 18:00:00  0.326746  0.565916  0.704173
2016-03-30 20:00:00  0.458807  0.565916  0.704173
2016-03-30 22:00:00  0.416415  0.565916  0.704173
2016-03-31 00:00:00  0.344517  0.487147  0.409475
2016-03-31 02:00:00  0.095404  0.487147  0.409475
2016-03-31 04:00:00  0.412321  0.487147  0.409475
2016-03-31 06:00:00  0.384827  0.487147  0.409475
2016-03-31 08:00:00  0.810305  0.487147  0.409475
2016-03-31 10:00:00  0.052873  0.487147  0.409475
2016-03-31 12:00:00  0.936284  0.487147  0.409475
2016-03-31 14:00:00  0.303524  0.487147  0.409475
2016-03-31 16:00:00  0.347630  0.487147  0.409475
2016-03-31 18:00:00  0.787372  0.487147  0.409475
2016-03-31 20:00:00  0.989716  0.487147  0.409475
2016-03-31 22:00:00  0.380994  0.487147  0.409475
2016-04-01 00:00:00  0.091029  0.091029  0.091029
```

Comment: Sorry for the late respond!
Thank you first of all for your answer. I have just tried your solution and i get this error message:

    peak = df.assign(hour=df.index.hour).query('8>= hour < 9').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).value.mean().rename('Peak')
AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'hour'

Comment: @O_Vizzle df = pd.DataFrame(dict(value=np.random.rand(len(tidx))), tidx)

Comment: Did you put tidx at end?